Realistic watercolor in Photoshop
I am desperately looking for a tutorial or course or motion, whatever - how to turn photos into realistic looking watercolors in Photoshop. I have tried common tutorials which can be found everywhere (with the sequence of filters dry brush, linocut, etc) and tried art history brush. The results look pretty nice, but not what I am looking for. :( I am looking rather for something like attached. Does anybody know how this is done, please?

You can use Photoshop's generative AI to create watercolours from a photo.  There's a good tutorial here: on youtube - I used this technique to create this example from some free stock photos from pixabay.

Thank you so much, will give it a try!

Here are some options.
1- Cheap ugly filters.
There are a lot of programs, even free that say that they will turn a photo into a watercolor one, but they look bad. so, let us ditch that option.
2- More Specialized filters.

I have used FilterForge and it has some interesting-looking filters. It has a large library you can browse and download.

There is one free that also looks interesting FotoSketcher


To control the results you can alter some variables of the filter, change the original resolution of the file, pre-adjust saturation, or things like that.
The example you posted has different types of strokes, so you might need to mask some parts, and composite them.
Here is a simple test layering 3 different filters from PhotoSketcher + Filter Forge.
I must say that the image needs to probably have some other processing before applying watercolor filters, probably some "cartoonyfier" to closely match the style you need.

3- Painting programs. The two options That come to my mind, are

Corel Painter https://www.painterartist.com/en/
Rebelle https://www.escapemotions.com/products/rebelle/about

Corel Painter has some features to make the brush strokes for you. They do not apply a filter but make individual strokes over the image.
There are some simpler versions of Painter, like Painter Essentials.
Rebelle can even simulate the water falling due to gravity. Spock would say, fascinating. https://www.escapemotions.com/experiments/rebelle/index.php
Another program that has some watercolor brushes is Krita.

Generative AI, some Programs allow you to upload an image and apply some styles to it.


Answering your specific question. I have not seen a realistic tutorial for Photoshop.
I found some actions for Photoshop. https://creativecloud.adobe.com/es/discover/article/transform-photos-into-watercolors-with-a-free-photoshop-action
It can be done by a combination of blending modes, brushes,  and masking, but personally, if you want to really paint them, use either Corel Painter or Rebelle.

Wow, thank you so much for such detailed reply, it was so helpful!! Will check the possibilities you mentioned. You are amazing! ❤️

Something to try to get photorealistic faces, but rough other areas(sorry for using only GIMP).
Duplicate your photo. Apply an artistic filter to the duplicate. The filter should leave approximately the original colors. If it doesn't you should adjust the colors of the original to resemble the colors of the filtered duplicate.
Insert a layer mask to the filtered duplicate. Paint manually to it so that the original becomes visible on the faces and other areas which should stay sharp:

The filtered version is on the top. It got white layer mask. Some black was painted to the mask to make the original face visible.
You can merge the layers and insert a paper imitating or other new background.Inserting a layer mask to the image layer and painting manually to the layer mask can trash the edges of the image. The painting to the mask must obey the same style as what's generated by filtering. I tried it, but it's not by any means a masterpiece:

Watercolors are not especially bright. Reducing the saturation levels can add realism. The next one is a preview of what CMYK printing could output. It makes the colors dull. In Photoshop or Krita you can convert an image to CMYK and (if needed) back to RGB. In GIMP you can get it only as a screenshot, but not as a saved file. This is such screenshot.


Using a less divisive subject matter may be better. Polictial content has no place here.

Many thanks you for your reply!! Will try it out!
